# How can I make so IIS SMTP uses Credentials when connecting

Tags: windows, iis, smtp

MY SMTP is working without any password or username, Iam trying to configurate my SMTP so it uses credentials when sending mail.

On my ASP.net app I have added credntials, but the SMTP works also without any credntials.

Does someone know how to configurate Windows IIS SMTP service to use credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the version, but generally go to the properties of the SMTP service, Access Tab, click the Authentication button.  There you can uncheck anonymous access and check the type of authentication you want (if you do basic, you should also configure SSL/TLS on the service first if any connections are over a network link).

Comment: well I changed the anonymous access.. and in the server I changed the credentials to Windows accounts, but it didn't work.